# How do I tell github that I made all of the commits pushed from my laptop?

Tags: git, github

So I have been pushing changes to my public repository (by signing in to my github account) from my laptop. The pushes from my laptop have an author listed as John Corser, and the commits I've done using github's editor (for the readme) show up as being written by johnpc (my github account). Checking the analytics, johnpc has only committed twice in the repository's history, but actually I am the top contributor.

How can I fix this in github?

[image: git history]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Github links authors and committers by email address, not by name. Use `git log` to look and see what the author and committer email addresses are on the commits in question. If you made commits with a valid email address, then just validate that email address with your github account, and then they will link to your github profile (in like a day or so). If you made commits with an invalid email address (git's default is usually something like username@localhostname ). Then you would have to rewrite all of the commits to fix this. (You wind up making new commits with new information, and moving all of the branch pointers to not reference any of the "bad" commits).

Comment: I used a valid email address, and I just now linked it to github! As soon as a made a new commit from this email address, all commits updated correctly. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

This is most probably happening due to incorrectly configured user name.

Open `~/.gitconfig` and `.git/config` in your project's root folder, & check if the user name field is present in either of them and is set correctly.

To correct older commits, use the following (it will rewrite commit information for all commits having johnpc as the user)

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter '
        if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_NAME" = "johnpc" ];
        then
                GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="John Corser";
                GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="John Corser";
                git commit-tree "$@";
        else
                git commit-tree "$@";
        fi' HEAD
```

---

***Edit***

After going through your repository on github, its clear that you're using 2 separate machines for committing your code, one with credentials `[johnpc, johnpc@email.domain]`, and another with credentials `[John Corser, john@email.domain]`. To do away with the discrepancy, in both of your machines, go to the project directory and run the following commands

```
$ git config user.name "johnpc"
$ git config user.email johnpc@email.domain
```

This standardises your project to use the same username, email from both locations, so all your future commits are safe.

Next, to correct your existing repo history, do

```
git filter-branch --commit-filter '
    if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_NAME" = "John Corser" ];
    then
            GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="johnpc";
            GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="johnpc";
            GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="johnpc@email.domain";
            GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="johnpc@email.domain";
            git commit-tree "$@";
    else
            git commit-tree "$@";
    fi' HEAD
```

Don't forget to alter the email id above to your actual email id (I've sanitised it to prevent it from getting publicly available)

Finally, force push your changes to your github account

```
git push -f origin master
```

Since you have a few other people contributing to this repository, ask them each to do a `git fetch` on their systems, and then do a `git checkout master && git rebase origin/master`. DO NOT DO A `git pull` or a `git fetch && git merge` at this stage.

Now all of you should have the updated code with appropriate commit history.

PS: Just to be on the safer side, you can create a backup clone of your github repo locally.

Comment: Will this change my commits to be by johnpc (my github profile name)? Or the other way around?

Comment: Also, running this doubled the number of commits in my project (just duplicated every commit :/)

Comment: @johncorser This shouldn't have doubled anything.. Can you tell me the exact sequence of commands you ran? Btw, this would have changed commit author from `"johnpc"` to `"John Corser"`

Comment: I wanted to change the name TO johnpc, and make it so github knew that my github account (johnpc) was the one who wrote the commit. The exact commands I typed were exactly what you put (in the grey box), followed by a `git push`